# How to unsubscribe from the GetResponse mailing list by the ID of the mailing list through the API?

Tags: getresponse

How to unsubscribe from the GetResponse mailing list by the ID of the mailing list through the API?

The documentation indicates only the possibility of unsubscribing by specifying the number of the message from which we can unsubscribe. And I need to unsubscribe from the mailing list, but I do not have a single message number.

Comment: well,what have you done so far?

Comment: As there will be time, I will lay out the decision full on With С#
on a fast I will tell that made through DELETE / contacts / {id}
1) I take a list of contacts for this newsletter.
2) on e-mail I find the user ID.
3) Delete user / contact by DELETE / contacts / {id}